# Different AutoCompleteSource for same textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have a textbox to input Name and Surname.

I want Suggestions for name as well as surname in same text box

Before hitting space(key) textbox should show suggestions of name.

After hitting space(key) in same textbox suggestions for surname should come.

```
Private Sub RunAutoFill()
    Dim collection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim name As New DataTable
    GetDataSetFromSqlToDataTable("Select Name from MstAutofill where Category = 'Name'", name)
    For i = 0 To name.Rows.Count - 1
        collection.Add(name.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
    Next
    txtName.MaskBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    txtName.MaskBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append
    txtName.MaskBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection
End Sub
```

Above code is used to set AutoCompleteSource from Database for Name

Comment: Thanks for telling us happy coding!

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: @nbadaud Please check edits..

Comment: Think it through.  Your custom collection must initially contain all the names you want to suggest and after adding a space it must contain all the surnames you want to suggest with each preceded by the name already entered.  You can detect the space using either the `TextChanged` event or the `KeyPress` event.

Comment: @jmcilhinney it is not possible to add each and every name with all the surname as i have more than 1000 names and surname so total combination will be 1000*1000 and for every new name it will create 1000 entries so it is not feasible. i want textbox to show suggestions for surname independent of name.

Comment: Please read what I actually wrote.